# Jenkins docker plugin does not work with systemd enabled CentOS image

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, systemd, jenkins-agent

I am trying to use docker slaves for Jenkins and I am using the [Docker plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/) for that.
This is my Dockerfile for the agent (base image - [centos/systemd](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/systemd)),

```
FROM centos/systemd

# Install a basic SSH server GIT, UNZIP, LSOF and JDK 8
RUN yum install -y openssh-server git unzip lsof java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless && yum clean all
# update sshd settings, create jenkins user, set jenkins user pw, generate ssh keys
RUN sed -i 's|session    required     pam_loginuid.so|session    optional     pam_loginuid.so|g' /etc/pam.d/sshd \
    && mkdir -p /var/run/sshd \
    && useradd -u 1000 -m -s /bin/bash -d /var/lib/jenkins jenkins \
    && echo "jenkins:jenkins" | chpasswd \
    && /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A \
    && echo export JAVA_HOME="/`alternatives  --display java | grep best | cut -d "/" -f 2-6`" >> /etc/environment

# Set java environment
ENV JAVA_HOME /etc/alternatives/jre

# Standard SSH port

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Docker plugin gives the below error when connecting to the container which is created using the image of the above Dockerfile.

But if I change the `FROM centos\systemd` to `FROM centos:centos7` ([centos official repo](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos)), then it works fine. But according to my requirements, I need **systemd** to be enabled ( I need to use service start/stop) inside the container.

The error I am receiving is as below,

```
Note: Disabled 5.4 sec ago due to error. Will re-enable in 4 min 54 sec.
Reason: Template provisioning failed.
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Volume` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('/sys/fs/cgroup') at [Source: (byte[])"{"Id":"eb09919709efda21fde8d5adde53269595840b347e4ac7053240c31c9180ca29","Created":"2021-01-01T05:20:58.375667629Z","Path":"/usr/sbin/sshd","Args":["-D","-p","22"],"State":{"Status":"running","Running":true,"Paused":false,"Restarting":false,"OOMKilled":false,"Dead":false,"Pid":36764,"ExitCode":0,"Error":"","StartedAt":"2021-01-01T05:21:02.240245172Z","FinishedAt":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},"Image":"sha256:85c2e377ecfcf2b0c0974b1160605a14e21fa3ce3957c8241984e852e0666555","ResolvConfPath":"/var/lib/d"[truncated 5310 bytes]; line: 1, column: 3550] (through reference chain: com.github.dockerjava.api.command.InspectContainerResponse["Mounts"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.github.dockerjava.api.command.InspectContainerResponse$Mount["Destination"])  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1590)  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1215)    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromString(StdDeserializer.java:311)    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1480)  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:207)   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:197) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138
```

Can someone please help to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The setup you describe – with systemd, multiple starting/stopping services, an ssh daemon, modified PAM configuration – sounds much more like a virtual-machine setup than a Docker container.  Does a VM (maybe built with a tool like Packer) meet your needs here?

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there any plugin similar to "Jenkins docker plugin" for VMs?